# Groovy Intersect 2 lists of Objects

Tags: groovy

I am trying to intersect 2 lists of POGOs.

What methods / interfaces do I need to implement on the POGO?

The documentation for the intersect method only states that it has to be an Iterable.

ie

```
list1 = createPOGOList()
list2 = createPOGOList()

list3 = list1.intersect(list2)
```

Where list1 and lists2 contain POGO's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You safest bet would be `Comparable` and the easiest way to get it for "free" is via [`Sortable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#xform-Sortable) AST transform.  E.g.

```
@groovy.transform.Sortable(includes=['id'])
class Pogo {
    Long id
}

def n = { new Pogo(id:it) }

assert [n(1),n(2)].intersect([n(1)])*.id == [1]
```

Comment: @tim_yates didn't work for me and then i followed the source and comparable is basically the first thing checked.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look tonight when I've got a computer :-)